# Safe to use a fork after touching drano?

Tags: cleaning

I used a metal fork to get something out of a clogged bathtub which had some drano in it. I washed the fork thoroughly afterwards and will run it through the dish washer.

Is the fork safe to use after?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product Drano will clean quite effectively things like a fork, as it designed to attack organic matter and that is the actual problem you maybe wishing to avoid.

So your fork will most likely be the cleanest thing in your home.  However a wash in hot water and soap and then rinse under running water will be enough to ensure you haven't anything from the drano remaining.

The final overkill step would be to put the fork in a container of water, if there is no visible reaction, it's clean.  Bonus if the container of water is dirty with oil from food.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the fork is entirely safe to use after washing. Drano is a combination of bleach and lye, both extremely water-soluble (and a thickener). It will rinse off of the fork easily; and after washing, will be entirely gone.